# JSP code to Struts or JSTL tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts

HI,

I m doing the folling stuff in the jsp code I need to do it using Struts or using JSTL tag can any body have relevant idea please share..

The following is my JSP code

```
<%

                        Object category = request.getAttribute("categoryDetails");
                        Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Integer>> cat = (Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Integer>>) category;
                        //out.print(cat.entrySet());

                        Set<String> functions = cat.keySet();

                        for(String fun : functions){

                            out.print("-----------");
                            out.print(fun);
                            out.print("-----------");

                            Hashtable<String, Integer> obj = cat.get(fun);

                            Vector<String> subFunction = new Vector<String>(obj.keySet());

                            Collections.sort(subFunction);

                            for(String str : subFunction){                            
                                out.print("#"+str+"-"+obj.get(str));
                                }
                        }



                        %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom tag or create a temporary view structure like this:

```
public class FunctionView {
    String functionName;
    List<SubFunctionView> subfunctions;

    public FunctionView(String functionName, List<SubFunctionView> subfunctions) {
        this.functionName = functionName;
        this.subfunctions = subfunctions;
    }

    public String getFunctionName() {
        return functionName;
    }

    public void setFunctionName(String functionName) {
        this.functionName = functionName;
    }

    public List<SubFunctionView> getSubfunctions() {
        return subfunctions;
    }

    public void setSubfunctions(List<SubFunctionView> subfunctions) {
        this.subfunctions = subfunctions;
    }
}

public class SubFunctionView {
    String subFunctionName;
    Integer value;

    public SubFunctionView(String subFunctionName, Integer value) {
        this.subFunctionName = subFunctionName;
        this.value = value;
    }


    public String getSubFunctionName() {
        return subFunctionName;
    }

    public void setSubFunctionName(String subFunctionName) {
        this.subFunctionName = subFunctionName;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then you just expost a method called List getFunctionsView() on your controller and use a simple nested jstl foreach loop.

Edit: Had to rework this one slightly.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use either, looking at the logic involved, I would rather write a custom jsp tag to achieve this. JSTL/Struts are equally good/horrible at doing this.